# how to replace element with fade animation using javascript (no jquery) and Promise or async/await?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I'm trying to replace an element using fade animation with only javascript. I figure it needs to use `Promise` and `async/await` mechanism so I tried to write the code below. the `fadeOut` process works fine, but somehow the 2nd element won't appear.. what am I doing wrong?

here's my code:

```js
const main = document.querySelector('#main');
const el0 = document.querySelector('.x');
const str = '<div class="asd1">Hello</div>'; // generated from fetch result
main.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', str);
const el1 = document.querySelector('.asd1');
(async() => {
  await fadeOut(el0, 1000);
  await fadeIn(el1, 1000);
})();

function fadeIn(elem, ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!elem)
      return;

    elem.style.opacity = 0;
    elem.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=0)";
    elem.style.display = "inline-block";
    elem.style.visibility = "visible";

    if (ms) {
      var opacity = 0;
      var timer = setInterval(function() {
        opacity += 50 / ms;
        if (opacity >= 1) {
          clearInterval(timer);
          opacity = 1;
        }
        elem.style.opacity = opacity;
        elem.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + opacity * 100 + ")";
      }, 50);
    } else {
      elem.style.opacity = 1;
      elem.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=1)";
    }

    resolve(elem);
  });
}

function fadeOut(elem, ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (!elem)
      return;

    if (ms) {
      var opacity = 1;
      var timer = setInterval(function() {
        opacity -= 50 / ms;
        if (opacity <= 0) {
          clearInterval(timer);
          opacity = 0;
          elem.style.display = "none";
          elem.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        elem.style.opacity = opacity;
        elem.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=" + opacity * 100 + ")";
      }, 50);
    } else {
      elem.style.opacity = 0;
      elem.style.filter = "alpha(opacity=0)";
      elem.style.display = "none";
      elem.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.asd1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0;
}

.x {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <div class="x">
    blah
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The promise is pointless since you aren't waiting for the animation to finish before resolving it.

Comment: Calculating all the steps with JS is a complicated and very inefficient approach to this problem. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event

Comment: you also have the [Animations API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Animations_API/Using_the_Web_Animations_API) - What you're doing is just —  not the way to do it. SetIntervals at 50ms, making DIVs inline-block, using visibility and display in the same pack, using opacity and filter in the same blocks... so many wrong things.

Comment: if you're using Promises but not the Animation API - you're simply doing it wrong

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I see.. in my defense, I copied the `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` functions from another SO answer so I didn't bother reading through all the codes hehe

Comment: joking aside, does anyone have a simple way to do it? I read the Animations API docs but it seems a bit too complicated for me..

Answer (score 0):

I finally remake the whole function into a simpler one like this and it works

```js
let elem = document.querySelector('.asd');
let elem2 = document.querySelector('.asd2');
let ms = 2000;
let intrvl = 20;
const action = fadeOut(elem, ms, intrvl);
action.then(response => {
  console.log('res', response);
  ms = 200;
  intrvl = 20;
  return fadeIn(elem2, ms, intrvl); 
}).then(response => {
  console.log('res2', response);
});

function fadeIn(elem, ms, intrvl) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let opacity = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
      opacity += intrvl/ms;
      elem.style.opacity = opacity;
      if (opacity >=1) {
        resolve('selesai fade in');
      }
    }, intrvl);
  });
}

function fadeOut(elem, ms, intrvl) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    let opacity = 1;
    setInterval(() => {
      opacity -= intrvl/ms;
      elem.style.opacity = opacity;
      if (opacity < 0) {
        elem.style.display = 'none';
        resolve('selesai fade out');
      }
    }, intrvl);
  });
}
```

```css
.asd {
  opacity: 1;
}

.asd2 {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="asd">Hello World!</div>
<div class="asd2">New Item!</div>
```